# 汁, ジュース and スープ

Tags: words

I know 汁 means both juice and soup. But I would like to know if there's a difference among them(汁 and ジュース)(汁 and スープ). Are all of them the same?

Comment: might help: http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1045805740

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- ジュース is most often used for a juice soft drink.  Some people will use it liberally to refer to ANY soft drink.　e.g. オレンジ・ジュース
- スープ is most often used in compound loan words, as in a specific kind of foreign soup.  e.g. ポテトスープ
- 汁 can be a Japanese broth, soup, or the raw juice of a fruit, or other liquids.  e.g. 豚汁, 果汁, 鼻汁